# showing image in center of screen css jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a large image on hovering a thumbnail in jquery and CSS. I have 2 images as

```
      <td>
        <% if camera["is_public"] == "t" %>
          <img src="https://media.evercam.io/v1/cameras/<%= camera["exid"] %>/thumbnail?" height="32" class="thumbnails">
          <img src="https://media.evercam.io/v1/cameras/<%= camera["exid"] %>/thumbnail?" height="600" class="full-image">
        <% else %>
          <img src="https://media.evercam.io/v1/cameras/<%= camera["exid"] %>/thumbnail?api_id=<%= camera["api_id"] %>&api_key=<%= camera["api_key"] %>" height="32" class="thumbnails">
          <img src="https://media.evercam.io/v1/cameras/<%= camera["exid"] %>/thumbnail?api_id=<%= camera["api_id"] %>&api_key=<%= camera["api_key"] %>" height="600" class="full-image">
        <% end %>
      </td>
```

and CSS as

```
.full-image {
  display: none;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 10%;
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  right: 34%;
}
```

on hovering `.thumbnail` am triggering this function

```
onImageHover = ->
  $("#snapshots_datatables").on "mouseover", ".thumbnails", ->
    nextImage = $(this).siblings(".full-image")
    $(nextImage).css({"top": "10%"})
    nextImage.show()

  $("#snapshots_datatables").on "mouseout", ".thumbnails", ->
    nextImage.hide()
```

all my problem is that i want to show `height: 600` image on hovering `.thumbnail` BUT in center of screen regarding screen size and Scroll. Even i scroll down image should apprea in center of screen. any help will be appreciated. I had zero luck in adding CSS by myself.

EDIT: same as bootstrap model even its clicked at very down in screen but it appears in middle of screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need javascript for this. I think css would do the trick.

First you want to make sure the .full-image is always in the center of your screen.

```
.full-image {
  position: fixed;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: -300px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

Then you want to make it appear when you hover on the .thumbnail

```
.thumbnail:hover .full-image {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's the working demo 
http://codepen.io/Jeffersonvdh/pen/GZBMBQ